# Social media links are going in the bottom right corner instead of the top right corner

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**Issue**

The social media links are going on the right bottom corner instead of top right, I searched how to position flex items vertically and I got to try align-items: start. I tried it and it didn't worked.

I used CSS grid to make the mobile style, and then flex in the media links to try to make it horizontal in tablet & desktop. I'm quite new in coding so I prefer simpler answers to understand.

```css
footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        "section-1 section-2";
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.section-1 {
    grid-area: section-1;
}

.section-2 {
    grid-area: section-2;
}

footer .section-1 ul {
    padding-left: 50px;
}

footer .section-2 ul {
    margin-right: 70px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

footer section ul li {
    padding: 3px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

footer section ul li h3 {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 22px;

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* < FOOTER > (desktop & tablet resolution) */
    footer {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
            "section-1 ";
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

    footer .section-1 ul {
        padding-left: 70px;
    }

    footer .section-2 ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        align-content: flex-start;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    footer section ul li {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    footer section ul li h3 {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    footer .section-2 ul li {
        padding: 0 18px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="page-wrap">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <!-- Site Links -->
    <section class="section-1">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3><a href="#">Title</a></h3>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- Social Media Links -->
    <section class="section-2">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reddit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Linkedin</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </footer>
</div>
```

**Image**

[Footer issue picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB0td.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this updated css :

```
    /* < FOOTER > (mobile) */
footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 0;
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

footer .section-1 ul {
    padding-left: 50px;
}

footer .section-2 ul {
    margin-right: 70px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

footer section ul li {
    padding: 3px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

footer section ul li h3 {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 22px;

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* < FOOTER > (desktop & tablet resolution) */
    footer {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
            "section-1 ";
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

    footer .section-1 ul {
        padding-left: 70px;
    }

    footer .section-2 ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        align-content: flex-start;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    footer section ul li {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    footer section ul li h3 {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    footer .section-2 ul li {
        padding: 0 18px;
    }
}
```

Comment: EDIT: Forgot to add tablet new code | Thank you! The desktop resolution looked what I expected but the mobile and tablet got some issues: | I fixed them by removing margin-right & padding left to margin-left: 160px in the mobile design | In tablet by replacing with display: inline-flex, float: right and margin right: 70px in the footer . section-2 UL. Keep contributing to the coding world my man!

Comment: Thanks too :-). Keep pushing !